# navigationcontroller to be set further down in navigation programmatically

Tags: iphone, button, uinavigationcontroller, back

I have a navigation controller going down through 4 screens/levels so users can make their choice, then they do a bunch of things in other screens and when finished, I set them back on the 4th view/screen/level of the navigation controller. Easy up to here... BUT
the back button brings them back to the bunch of things (obviously) and not to the 3rd level which I wish!

How to do this please? I really would like to avoid "overwritting" the back button and would like a more elegant way of going down programatically very quickly so all is set correctly

thanks for your help

geebee

EDIT 1:
Thanks Jason for taking the time to help me - appreciated.
The thing is that I would not know how where to put that statement as the logical place would be in the callback of the "back" function - which I would need to create as I don't see it and it might mess up with the normal "back" button when I drill down naturally.

What I really want to do is to do in an invisible manner is to be back at level 1 and go down programatically to level 3 (so like that it looks like I went back 1 from 4 to 3 - exactly like I wanted where in reality I went down 1, 2, 3) - and then if the user continues to want to go back it just goes back naturally because I drilled down initially normally.

hope I am clear

EDIT 2:
you are right Jason. when I am doing the bunch of other things I am not pushing any more view controllers - I am totally somewhere else in my application asking some questions and getting answers to it several times. Then at the end of these tasks, I need to position myself back on my last navigation controller which was level 4 so I simply launch it - and then I have the problem with the back button... I know exactly how I went down from level 1 to level 4 through singleton class (acting as global variable) so it is why I was thinking may be I should invisibly position myself on level1 and drill down to level 4 so the back button works like it should.
thanks again for taking the time as I am stuck.

Comment: Why are you overriding then? If you don't default behaviour is to pop to last view on the stack.

Comment: I finally solved it thanks to you guys making me think what I was doing. I saved in a global variable (singleton pattern) the instance of the UINavigatiionController; then I used popToRoot to come back to the root of my navigation ; then in turn I pop my views 2 and 3 with NO animation ; and pop my view 4 with animation. Result is when I click on back it has the expected behavior to go to view 3.Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is this method?

```
- (NSArray *)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

so something like

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:thirdLevelViewController animated:YES]
```

EDIT: geebee, in your initial question "going down through 4 screens/levels so users can make their choice, ***then they do a bunch of things in other screens and when finished***"

Could you explain to us what you mean by that line? I think that's what is confusing the people trying to answer your question right now. Are you pushing more viewcontrollers onto the stack whilst doing these other things?

The only way pressing back would go to your other screens is if you have only been pushing view controllers onto the stack but never popping them. I think that may possibly be your problem? I can't really say much without seeing the code.

EDIT2: geebee, I'm not quite sure I understand what's happening in your application, I'm not sure how much more I might be able to assist you unless I can see some of the code which your trying to do things with

Comment: I finally solved it thanks to you guys making me think what I was doing. I saved in a global variable (singleton pattern) the instance of the UINavigatiionController; then I used popToRoot to come back to the root of my navigation ; then in turn I pop my views 2 and 3 with NO animation ; and pop my view 4 with animation. Result is when I click on back it has the expected behavior to go to view 3.Thanks!

Comment: glad you sorted it out :) although might not be the most elegant solution...whatever works ey?

Comment: I am a purist too but I actually think it is ok as it is only 4 lines of code and a variable so clear to read and maintain - rather than a dodgy formula to understand how much I need to go back up in the stack with always the possibility to get it wrong and then crash - cheers - and thanks again